# How to omit the spaces in a string

Tags: c, string, spaces

I need to write a program that will read in a sentence and output the number of words in the sentence. I have the program done, but the problem is that my program is counting the spaces inbetween the words as characters. How do I omit those spaces and just display the number of words in the string? I was thinking I need some type of loop, but I don't know how to execute it.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#define pause system("pause")

main() {
char mystring[155];
int counter = 0;

printf("Enter your name: ");
scanf("%[^\t\n]", &mystring); 
printf("Your name is %s\n", mystring);

// find out the number of characters in the string
counter = strlen(mystring); 
printf("There are %i words in the sentence. \n", counter);

// find out how many WORDS are in the sentence. Omit spaces



pause;
} // end of main
```

Comment: HINT: think you need a loop in there and count the words, skip the punctuation characters, but I'm not going to write your program for you.

Comment: Words or characters? You say words but your code seems to be counting chars.

Answer (score 0):

Again, as someone has already said, use strtok. If you need to know more about it,
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/

If you want to do it without using any existing API's (I don't know why you would want to do that unless it's a class project), then create a simple algorithm with a pointer to traverse the string and skip spaces while incrementing count.

As people have said before, this will be a good exercise for you, so don't ask for code. And there's always google..

Answer (score 0):

Your function would look something like this :

```
_getNumberOfWords(char[] string) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i=0; string[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (string[i] == " ") {
        for (int j=i; string[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            // This is to handle multiple spaces
            if (string[j] != " ") break;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

You could also try to do a :

```
char * strtok ( char * string, const char * " " );
```